# AWS API Gateway : route error

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I created my API in EC2 instance of AWS. when I'm deploying my API in to AWS Api gateway. API Gateway provided me with a link. When I used that same link in postman to access my API, I'm getting the following error, despite providing IAM credentials.
The Error I'm facing is

`{
  "message": "No method found matching route / for http method GET."
}`

Comment: Does your API have a `GET` method defined on the `/` resource, or is it a different method (e.g. `POST`)?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it. The problem is in the Invoke URL you're using. To fix this, please correct path: check the Deployment API link + double check what method you want to call.

You may need to add some more path variables after "/". E.g., "test", whatever, so path finishes with method you'd like to invoke.

I created test project for you, please see screenshot with example. So, in order for script to execute math operation, e.g. "add", you add "/math/add", not default invoke URL:

[image: Test deployment]

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Auth" section of your method request in the API gateway.

I had the same response until I set Auth to "AWS_IAM"
[image: API Gateway]